# xargs -I replace-str in find ... -exec sed

Tags: bash, sed, find, xargs

I'm on GNU/Linux system with Bash 4.4.23 and I have a file with some Bash variables:

ex.

```
export VARONE="var1"
export VARTWO="var2"
...
```

I have to replace the `${VARIABLE}` with `{{VARIABLE}}` in other files with ".template" extension under "templates" folder.

I try to execute this command:

```
cat varfile \
  | grep export \
  | awk -F '=' '{print $1}' \
  | awk '{print $2}' \
  | xargs -I var -- \
      find templates -type f -iname "*.template" \
        -exec sed 's/${var}/{{var}}/g' {} \;
```

but I had no luck :( it seems that sed does not match with this LHS, infact it prints the original file as output.

Someone can explain what is wrong with the command above?

Comment: You need the `-i` option to `sed` to make it update the files in place. Otherwise it just prints the result on standard output.

Comment: just as an aside, if you end a line with a pipe character (`|`) you don't need to escape the newline, and can still indent the next command.  You could `grep export varfile` as the first line and wouldn't need the `cat`. If you use square braces you can list multiple characters as delimiters for `awk` and might be able to consolidate your two `awk` commands. None of this *answers* your question; it's just observations as an aside that you might want to tweak for ease of reading and maybe performance, though I doubt performance is exactly killing you on this. :)

Comment: @PaulHodges thanks for your advice, StackOverflow has added the newline escapes automatically, maybe because I have wrote all commands in one line.
I didn't know the multiple delimiters option for awk, I've really apreciate that.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you are right, I've realized that the missing of -i to test the command has leads me to fall in error, my command actually does its work well when writes the substitutions into the file, many thanks.

Comment: @PaulHodges The escapes came from ruakh's edit.

Answer (score 1):

The only issue seems like the lack of `-i` flag and the unescaped `$` for sed.

Here's a simpler, tested, initial pipeline with aforementioned fixes:

```
sed -nE '/^export /{s///;s/([^=]+).*/\1/;p;}' varfile |
    xargs -I var -- find templates -name '*.template' -exec sed -i '' 's/\${var}/{{var}}/g' {} +
```

For assurance, I added a `g` flag if the variable appears more than once per line.

Comment: Why the `s///;`?

Comment: The escape of $ char seems to be not needed because in strings enclosed between single apices, bash doesn't do substitutions while xargs does the substituition of "var" correctly. 
Thanks for your improvements to my code.

Comment: Indeed this may work with most sed implementations (perhaps all?). This was not done in fear of bash interpolation, however, this was done because `$` is a meta char (anchoring text post-EOL is nonsensical---apparently sed understands the intent nonetheless).